# Android - ResourceNotFoundException for application label

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am wondering if anyone can help me. I am getting a ResourceNotFoundException in my android application. 
It occurs when the following code is run (the exception occurs on the `getString()` call)

```
        context = getApplicationContext();
        PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        String appName = context.getString(pInfo.applicationInfo.labelRes);
```

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` I have the `android:label` attribute set for the application and activtiy tags.

When I 
use the debugger I can see that the `PackageInfo.ApplicationInfo` object contains value 0 for `labelRes` and that explains the exception.

The weird thing is that the value that I set for the `android:label` attribute in `AndroidManifest.xml` is contained in the
`nonLocalizedLabel` attribute. Does anyone know how this could happen?
I have checked that the package name returned by the context object is the correct one for my application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to this. The solution was to use

```
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getApplicationInfo();
        String appName = (String) context.getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(appInfo);
```

instead and it worked